# How to open port 21?

Tags: server, ftp, iptables, nmap

I installed `vsftpd` in my Linux Server 12.04. Unfortunately my firewall closed port 20 and 21. So I used the commands found [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/iptables-open-ftp-port-21/) and other commands to open my ports. But I tested with `nmap` and I saw ports didn't open.

What can I do? I need to open these ports.

Comment: What firewall are you using?

Comment: What firewall software are you using?

Comment: My firewall is iptables

Comment: Try `ufw allow in ftp`

Comment: Some ISPs block ports 20 and 21, did you make sure your ISP allows them?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes a port will need to be forwarded from the router (take a look at port forwarding), or perhaps port 21 is already pointing to something else on the network?

Answer (score 1):

On the website there was these 2 lines

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT
```

After that you may need to restore your iptables rules with:

```
iptables-restore < LOCATION_OF_IPTABLES_RULES_FILE
```

Comment: Thank you but dosn't work. terminal sey to me::                    -A: command not found

Comment: Instead of -A please try it with -I

Comment: Dosn't work. but I can solved my problem, I wrote 'iptables -F' in terminal and 'Listen 21' in /etc/apache2/ports.conf and then restart apache. Thank you

Comment: Make sure your ISP allows you to use those ports, there are ISPs that will block those ports automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue, installing ftpd in ubuntu 18.04.

A telnet on port 21 is blocking (local network).

Apply the following command as root

```
ufw allow in ftp
```

and the port is opened.